# Angular 5 DOM not updating on array push

Tags: socket.io, angular5

I'm making a really basic chatroom for a website, which uses socket.io to receive and send chat messages (socket.io because the backend, nodejs, was written using that).
Almost everything works, only:
When a user sends a message, the message will appear in his chatlist, but no one else's list is updated till they refresh the page.

So how it works: user types a message, that message is sent with socket.io to the server.
Then the server sends back the message to everyone with socket.io and the message appears in everyone's chatlist.

The server does send back the chat message, but only to the sender.

My code (only code):

chat.component.ts:

```
Usersonline: number;
socketio;
messages = [] = [];

constructor(private socket: SocketconnectorService) {
this.socketio = socket.socket;
this.socketio.on('getOldChat', (data) => {
  this.messages.push(data);
});
this.socketio.on('getChat', (data) => {
  this.messages.push(data);
});
}

sendChat(chatmessage) {
console.log('Sending new message: ' + chatmessage);
this.socketio.emit('sendChat', chatmessage);
}
```

socketconnector.service.ts:

```
  public socketurl = 'http://serverip:8080';
  public socket;

constructor() {
  this.socket = io(this.socketurl);

}
```

chat.component.html:

```
<div id="message" style="color: white">
    <div *ngFor="let message of messages">
        <li class="chatmessage">{{ message }}</li>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="input-box">
    <input class="input-box-inside" #chatmessage (keyup.enter)="sendChat(chatmessage.value);chatmessage.value='' ">
  <button id="input-box-send" (click)="sendChat(chatmessage.value)" type="button"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i></button>
</div>
```